# Appium: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: 'java -version' failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

I have written below code in @Test method:

```
File app = new File("E:\\AppiumWorkspace\\apk\\redBus.apk");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        // capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
         capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"XOLO Q1010");
         capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.2.2");
         capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

       capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "in.redbus.android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "in.redbus.android.activity.SplashScreen");


        dr = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

On Running code from eclipse I am getting below error on eclipse:

```
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --full-reset --platform-name Android --platform-version 17 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","fullReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"17","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"4.2.2","app":"E:\\AppiumWorkspace\\apk\\redBus.apk","deviceName":"XOLO Q1010","platformName":"Android","appActivity":"in.redbus.android.activity.SplashScreen","appPackage":"in.redbus.android"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)
> info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: E:\AppiumWorkspace\apk\redBus.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 308ffbc6-2e50-4c9d-bffc-442500683e20
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -version"
> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 
> info: [debug] Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -version"
> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1057:17)
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:758:5)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1184:11)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>     at Pipe.close (net.js:484:11)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c \"java -version\"\n'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n)","origValue":"'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c \"java -version\"\n'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 230.274 ms - 526
```

I re-installed java nut it did not helped. I received same error.

On Eclipse I am having below error:

```
FAILED: testApp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -version"
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 503 milliseconds
```

I have verified ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME path and those are pointing to correct locations. I ran adb devices command on cmd and it gives me correct output.

Can anyone please help me sorting out this problem.

Following is the content of PATH:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%;
```

Comment: I hope some of the system inbuilt library paths are missing. Please add them and try it out.

Comment: Please check you java home path

Comment: Can you just post what are the paths available under PATH. So we can confirm the issue.

Comment: I have added content on PATH to the post.

Comment: Can you check what is there under **%SystemRoot%**. i hope it should be **C:\Windows**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added bin path to your path environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I have added bin path

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you try `java -version` from the cmd at any directory location once and match the result with the java version that Eclipse is using for the project to build in `Project Settings.`
2. Session is not created because your project requires a java version which is not available on your system as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope some of the system inbuilt library paths are missing. Please add them and try it out.
For Ex: It should be having system specified default paths. i hope some path might got deleted. Please add it and try.

**`For EX: PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v 1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared`**